# Arrays from XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

Maybe someone could help?

I am extracting data from XML that's been returned via curl_init, got this far with the code that's been provided foreach($xml->Outputs->Company->Type as $quoteBlock)

```
foreach($xml->Outputs->Company->Type as $quoteBlock)
    {
        
        foreach($quoteBlock->Company as $arr)
        {
    
            $companyName=(string)$arr->Name;
            $amount=(string)$arr->samount;
            $quote[$blockDesc][$companyName]=$premium;
         
        }
        
    }
```

This is the response I get with each company which is A and so has an amount

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [A] => 25.59
            [B] => 24.53
            [C] => -
            [D] => 24.57
            [E] => 29.11
            [F] => 25.59
        )
```

Is there a way to make a variable for each company, for example, $acompany is the value number 25.59 from company A?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to take a company 'Amazon' with an amount '25.55' and change that into a variable `$Amazon=25.59;` You can create dynamic variables like `$$companyName=$amount` but you will have to validate that variable to remove non-alphamuneric charaters and the first char cant be a number. In fact, it's probably best just to remove any numbers at all. Something like

```
$companyname = "Amazon Prime";
$var = strtolower(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z]/", '', $companyname));
$$var = $amount;
```